# How to make that when the Webview close the Flask will also quit or the flask will automatically terminated

Tags: python, flask, webview

## How to make that when the Webview close the Flask will also quit or the flask will automatically terminated

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, render_template
import webview

app = Flask(__name__)


tk = Tk()

tk.geometry("800x450")


webview.create_window('TITLE', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html', message='Hello, World!')


def run_flask_app():
    app.run()


def main():
    # Create a separate thread to run Flask app
    flask_thread = Thread(target=run_flask_app)

    # Start the Flask thread
    flask_thread.start()

    # Start the webview
    webview.start()

    # Wait for the Flask thread to finish
    flask_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## FIX THAT

when the webview will close the flask will automatically terminated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down the flask development server is more easily achieved if it is started with the subprocess or multiprocessing modules rather than threading. There is a section in the werkzeug documentation on shutting down the server at https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/serving/#shutting-down-the-server but the example given there does not exactly fit your use case.

I have used the subprocess module and have split your code into separate server and user interface scripts. This also has the benefit of decoupling your desktop user interface from your backend code so that you could host it on the internet without any code changes in the future if you so wished.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html', message='Hello, World!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

ui.py

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = subprocess.Popen(["python", "server.py"])

    input() # Do your tk user interface stuff here instead of input()

    server.terminate()
```